# SQLite in VS2015 MVC 6.0.0-beta8 not working

Tags: asp.net, sqlite, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-mvc

Can't get SQLite to work on an `MVC6 beta 8` project.

To reproduce the problem, [**assuming you have beta 8 already installed**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49442) in Visual Studio 2015:

1. Create a new empty WebApi project under `ASP.NET 5 Preview Templates`
2. In project.json, under `frameworks` remove `dnx5`, leaving just `dnx451`
3. Create an empty `test.dat` file in your `wwwroot` folder
4. Install latest 1.0.98.1 `SQLite` with Nuget: `Install-Package System.Data.SQLite`
5. In `startup.cs` add `using System.Data.SQLite` and `System.IO` and put this 2 lines into `public Startup(...`

   `string folder = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();`

   `SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source="+folder+"test.dat");`

Hit `F5` and you will get `Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'`

There are lot of questions and answers about this topic for previous versions of VS... I tried mostly everything including building for `x86` and `x64`, install other nuget packages (Core / PCL / bare SQLite / Entity, etc) and so on.
There are some workaround copying files by hand, but I need this to deploy on a server without much intervention.

Its hard to believe that the most used compact database in the world can't work out of the box in VS2015, so I'm hopping that I'm doing something incredibly wrong and someone can shed some light.

Thanks.-

Answer (score 0):

I feel you try this link [SqlLite in EF7](http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/uwp.html). The page refers UWP, but it still can be used with ASP.NET MVC6.

Comment: I added `Install-Package EntityFramework.SQLite –Pre` to the project... no luck

Comment: are you getting same error or different? Just follow those steps in link properly. I was able to create it successfully.

Comment: I just added the package I mentioned. I didn't follow the steps since I don't want a gigantic EF project (quite the contrary :))

Comment: However, reading the article down the line pointed me in the right direction, which is `Microsoft.Data.SQLite`

Comment: EF7 is not gigantic now, if you observe steps if your using only SqlLite, then add only EF7 SqlLite packages and EF7 command package to run EF7 commands. Its not huge as it use to in EF6. Just give try.Glad that link was helpful.

Comment: Will do! Tried to upvote you but my score is to low :-/ Sorry

Comment: If it helps you, thats more important. Getting directions is important

Answer (score 0):

Not a real solution but a decent workaround for anyone with the same problem.

Use `Microsoft.Data.SQLite`

You would need to make some minor adjustment to the class names like `SQLiteConnection` to `SqliteConnection` but it works.